# redirect flask for html

Tags: python, flask

while running the platform for signing up request:
when submiting form it doesn't redirect me as i want to the home page

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for,flash,redirect
from formapp import Regist_form, Login_form
app= Flask(__name__,template_folder='webpages')
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='6bdss5z9884s56q6662x3xdde3f'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
@app.route('/regist',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def regist():
    form= Regist_form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'account created for {{ form.username.data }}!' ,'success')
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
#       print (form.username.data)
#   else:
#       flash(f'account created for { form.username.data }!' ,'error')
#       return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('regist.html',form=form)
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    form=Login_form
    return render_template('login.html',form=form)
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need `url_for` to redirect...

Replace this:

```
return redirect(url_for("home"))
```

for this:

```
return redirect("/", code=302)
```

`code=302` tells flask there's no problem in order to redirect